# Unable to see HDRI in background

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, hdri

I've just been looking at various similar questions and can't seem to find the solution so thought I'd try asking here juts in case someone has had a similar issue.

I've been working with this project for a while now and suddenly the HDRI stopped showing as a background in rendered view. I've been using cycles but changed it to Eevee and still doesn't show. I've checked everything in the world settings and the viewport shade settings and still isn't showing. The lighting seems to be fine, it's just the lack of image.

Apologies in advance if this is a really easy obvious thing! I'm very new to Blender and would appreciate some help from someone a little more experienced than me.

[image: screenshot of workspace]

Thanks!
Anna

Comment: Under Render properties > Film, do you have 'Transparency' checked? If so, uncheck it and try rendering again.

Comment: It's now working, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your screenshot, your view is set to *Ortographic* not *Perspective*, this usually makes the HDRI just a blurred color instead of a real image. You can toggle between those views with <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd>. However, then there is still color, but your viewport shows this grey checker texture which means you've set the background to *Transparent*. Go to *Render Properties* > *Film* > *Transparent* and disable it.

[image]

Comment: That's really helpful thank you! It's now working. Apologies for the late reply I haven't been working on this project for the week because of uni deadlines.

Comment: You're welcome! You might consider to mark the answer as "Accepted" to indicate others with similar problems that a solution is found. Read more about it here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

I had to click "Use Nodes" (World >> Surface)